# Create Grand Total from to worksheets with unrelated tables on Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I am trying to sum data from two worksheets that use unrelated data on a Tableau Dashboard.  Sheet one totals revenues from database source A.  Sheet two totals revenues from database source B.  There isn't any like data to link the two databases to calculate one total

Linking data - won't work.  Data unique to each database

None

{Grand Total on worksheet A from database A}+{Grand Total on worksheet B from database B] = DASHBOARD GRAND TOTAL

Comment: What type of datasource are you using?

Comment: How about making an artificial link between the two so you can blend, and then make a metric as above?  Make a column equal to 1 in each dataset, blend on that, then sum your data as you describe.